# Enable/Disable Tab in ActionBar

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

It's possible to enable/disable Tabs in ActionBar?
With TabHost this is not a problem.. I do:

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setVisibility(true);
```

and all works.. but if i want to do the same thing with Tabs in ActionBar?? 
In Tab class don't exist `setEnable();`

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
Tab tab =  bar.newTab();
tab.setText("Test");
tab.setEnable(false); /*DON'T EXIST!!*/
```

How can I do??

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [`removeTab( ActionBar.Tab tab )`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#removeTab%28android.app.ActionBar.Tab%29)-method of `ActionBar`:

```
bar.removeTab( tab );
```

And then use the [`addTab( ActionBar.Tab tab, int position )`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#addTab%28android.app.ActionBar.Tab,%20int%29) to put it back in, provided that you save the position of the `Tab` you removed:

```
bar.addTab( tab, savedTabPosition );
```

Comment: This is not the same thing.. i don't want to remove then re-add... i would only make it enable/disable... i want that the tab still appear in the layout! Thanks for your asnwer

Comment: I've posted another suggestion in a new answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this - that will be up to you, but it should give you an general idea on how you could handle your problem.

There are three steps:

**First step**

We need something that can handle the enable/disable action for us. For this purpose we create the following class:

```
public class TabItem {
  private Tab tab;
  private Fragment fragment;
  private boolean enabled;

  public TabItem( Tab tab, Fragment fragment ) {
    this.tab = tab;
    this.fragment = fragment;
    enabled = true;
  }

  public Tab getTab() {
    return tab;
  }

  public Fragment getFragment() {
    return fragment;
  }

  public void toggleEnabled() {
    enabled = enabled ? false : true;
  }

  public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
  }
}
```

**Second step**

We need something that can hold these `TabItems` and an easy way to access them. For this purpose we add the following class:

```
public class TabHolder {
  private HashMap<Integer, TabItem> tabs;

  public TabHolder() {
    tabs = new HashMap<Integer, TabItem>();
  }

  public void addTab( TabItem tab ) {
    tabs.put( tab.getTab().getPosition(), tab );
  }

  public TabItem getTab( int position ) {
    return tabs.get( position );
  }
}
```

**Third step**

We need to handle the selection of `Tabs` ourselves, so we need to create a custom `TabListener`:

```
private class MyTabListener implements TabListener {
  @Override
  public void onTabReselected( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft ) {
    //Do nothing - unless you want to do something.
  }

  @Override
  public void onTabSelected( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft ) {
    TabItem item = tabHolder.getTab( tab.getPosition() );
    if( item.isEnabled() ) {
      ft.remove( item.getFragment() );
      ft.commit();
    }        
  }

  @Override
  public void onTabUnselected( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft ) {
    //Do nothing - unless you want to do something.        
  } 
}
```

**Finally**

We can now utilize our created framework. To do so, we need a `TabHolder`:

```
tabHolder = new TabHolder(); //Needs to be declared in the same class as our TabListener
```

We need to add our `Tabs` to this:

```
tabHolder.addTab( new TabItem( tab, fragmentForThisTab ) );
```

And we need to set our custom `TabListener` on each `Tab`:

```
tab.setTabListener( new MyTabListener() );
```

**Enable/Disable**

To enable or disable a `Tab` we simply call:

```
tabHolder.getTab( position ).toggleEnabled();
```

---

Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: How would this be incorporated with the ActionBar?

Comment: You call tabHolder.getTab(position).getTab() to get the tab and then add that to the ActionBar.

Comment: But ActionBar.addTab takes an ActionBar.Tab, which TabItem is not compatible with.

Comment: Calling the getTab-method on the TabItem should give you an instance of ActionBar.Tab.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't help you use one of these TabItems does it?

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way to remove the Tabs-bar from the Actionbar. Just type:

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
```

This will remove any tabs-bar.

Comment: actionbar.removeAllTabs()

Answer (score 0):

you can override:
  `public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`, in here set the tab enable/disable for example:

```
menu.findItem(R.id.send).setEnabled(mMessageNeedtoSend);
```

and then you can set the `mMessageNeedtoSend` true or false,call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`  to refresh ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but hope this workaround might help others who are interested in this issue.

```
private Handler mHandler;
private int mLastSelectedTabIndex = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...

    mHandler = new Handler();

    // ...

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

    Tab tab = bar.newTab().setText("Enabled Tab")
            .setTabListener(mTabListener);
    bar.addTab(tab);

    tab = bar.newTab().setText("Disabled Tab")
            .setTabListener(mTabListener);
    bar.addTab(tab);
}

private TabListener mTabListener = new TabListener() {
    // ...

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        int position = tab.getPosition();
        if (position == 1) {
            // Disabled tabs are selected.

            mHandler.postAtFrontOfQueue(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                            mLastSelectedTabIndex);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Enabled tabs are selected. Do something on your own.

            mLastSelectedTabIndex = position;
        }
    }

    // ...
};
```

If you are using `ViewPager` with it as usual, you can simply utilize its position instead of `mLastSelectedTabIndex` like this:

```
getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

Comment: http://suhas1989.wordpress.com/2014/10/13/enable-or-disable-actionbar-tab-in-android/ Working example.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by two simple steps(Assuming you set custom view to the tabs):

1- Disable function: Avoid changing tabs

```
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        int position = tab.getPosition();
        if (mModifyMode) {
            mPagerAdapter.changeFragment(position);
        }
    }
```

2- Disable click events:

```
    public void setModifyMode(boolean modifyMode) {
        mModifyMode = modifyMode;
        for (int i = 0; i < mActionBar.getTabCount(); i++) {
            View parent = (View) mActionBar.getTabAt(i).getCustomView().getParent();
            parent.setEnabled(mModifyMode);
        }
    }
```

I tested it right now and it is working ;)