# How to disable switching between tabs in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want my action bar to be displayed in NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS but switching between tabs should be disabled.
Can anyone please help me on this.
I am trying to do this by actionbar.getCustomView, and then trying to setClickable(false) for the action bar view.

But the custumview is received Null.

Dont know what is the problem here..

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that action bar navigation (including `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`) is deprecated in the "L" developer preview, and I understand that it will remain deprecated in the production release of Android based on "L".

Comment: Is this helpful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165008/enable-disable-tab-in-actionbar

Comment: thanks for your help lanB ...it did not help... its a work around of removing tabs....but i want that tabs should be there but they should not be selectable... like they should gray out so that user is not able to switch tabs